# Display Port 1.4 Hot Plug Detect (HPD) Behaviour on AMD 7040 Motherboard

Tags: display, motherboard, x86, displayport, hot-plug

For some reason I can't get my DP port working on the AMD 7040 motherboard that I have designed, where on the same board, I have also Mini-DP that has an identical electrical circuit (in schematic) and it's working perfectly.

NOTE: in BIOS, both ports are chosen as (DP Display).

[Schematic Design for both ports.](https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/08dvYhVvY1IseIa7QNMEo4Tqw#DP_Mini_DP_Design)

What I notice that when I plug a cable into the Mini-DP, the HPD changes from 100mV to 2.6V.
But Plugging Full-Size DP Cable into the DP Connector doesn't change the HPD for this port, and goes from 100mV to absolute 0V.

It could be that this pin is being shorted to ground upon connecting, where it could be assembly problem for the DP [connector](https://www.searchdatasheet.com/pdfviewer?url=https%3A%2F%2Fpdf.searchdatasheet.com%2Fdatasheets-1%2Fhon_hai_precision_industry_%255Bfoxconn%255D%2F3VD51203-H7JJ-7H.pdf).
According to what I saw on camera, the pins are soldered as supposed to be, there is no short. What else could be causing the problem?

Also, making sure that I understand the concept of HPD correctly. the HPD is a signal that should be first initiated by the Sink to the Source, which means, once I connect a DP Cable from the sink, I should immediately see that the HPD on the connector is HIGH. (Even when the source is still didn't get all the EDID data from the SINK).
I'm asking this in order to debug the problem, and see if the problem could be Auxiliary/DATA signals problem.

Note: The DP connector (J24) Chassis pins are not connected to anything, that will be fixed in next spin, but that should not cause the problem (I also manually tried to solder them on board to CHASSIS GND, but there was no change in behavior).